# Finding the version of the compiled executable

Tags: linux, gcc, ldd

I'm trying to create a script which detects binary files and gets the version which compiled it. For example, if I have an executable which was compiled with `gcc`, I would like to get the version of `gcc`. I find out that I can use the Linux command `ldd` in order to check the executable, but is there a proper/cleaner and better way to do so?

Also as I understand, some of the python files also being compiled with `gcc`. How can I detect the version?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the binary format that you are looking at. As you mention Linux, I am assuming ELF files.

For that, you could use `objdump -s --section .comment file`:

```
my_executable:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20285562 756e7475 20372e33  GCC: (Ubuntu 7.3
 0010 2e302d31 36756275 6e747533 2920372e  .0-16ubuntu3) 7.
 0020 332e3000                             3.0.
```

For clang this looks like

```
my_executable:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20285562 756e7475 20382e31  GCC: (Ubuntu 8.1
 0010 2e302d31 7562756e 74753129 20382e31  .0-1ubuntu1) 8.1
 0020 2e300063 6c616e67 20766572 73696f6e  .0.clang version
 0030 20362e30 2e302d31 7562756e 74753220   6.0.0-1ubuntu2
 0040 28746167 732f5245 4c454153 455f3630  (tags/RELEASE_60
 0050 302f6669 6e616c29 00                 0/final).
```

Another option, which is a bit more difficult to parse, would be to use `strings`:

```
strings hyrise/build-clang/hyriseClient | grep clang
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final) | head -n 1
```

Note that on Linux, clang might use ld from gcc, so even if the executable was built using clang, you might see both "GCC" and "clang" in the output.

Comment: Great answer (didn't know about this commend). How can I extract the exact version of  `gcc` out of `objdump` output?

Comment: You'll probably need some string manipulation for that. I can't find an easy way to get it as a proper single-line string.